# By passing MDM configuration in ios

Tags: ios, swift, mdm

We are fetching MDM configurations via 'UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")' and this information is being sent back to headers of login api to further check for security reasons. My question is can we bypass MDM configuration check when we test the app or debug anything and create the static auth secret key and sed that to API header for authentication?

So far searched about this on internet but nothing worked for me.